# why not compile in link function of directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is my code

```
// index.html
<my-slider items="items"></my-slider>

// slider.tpl.html
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">  // items.length = 10
    <my-thumb my-data="item"></my-thumb>
  </li>
</ul>



// slider.directive.js
angular.module('app')
.directive('mySlider', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'slider.tpl.html',
    scope: {
       items: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log(scope.items); // print [{...},{...},{...}.....] 
      var elem.find('ul').css('width', _.sumBy(elem.find('li'), function (o) { $(o).width(); })); 

      // but
      console.log(elem.find('li').size()); // print => 0  ???? why is 0?
    }
  };
});
```

I want to set full width to the ul element, but this

```
elem.find('li').size() = 0
```

why is it empty?

Answer (score 1):

you need to let `ng-repeat` render first

try using `$timeout` so the code won't run until next digest

```
.directive('my-slider', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    //.....
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
       $timeout(function(){
          console.log(elem.children().length)
      });
    }
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/iiYETC4SNo9QSiPvwEo9)**</kbd>

Comment: if you need the child elements to render ... yes. Or you can use `$last` property of a child directive to send event to parent or trigger a function in parent. If you will be changing data in `ng-repeat` that may be more practical